# React Redux RTK mutation CORS error in AWS API Gateway with API-key

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have problem with the Redux Tool Kit (RTK) in React. I'm trying to send a request to API Gateway (REST API) with API key. The CORS in API Gateway looks like following:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,X-Api-Key',
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000',
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST'
```

This is how the RTK api looks like

```js
const myApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'myApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: 'https://my-api.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/api',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Api-Key': 'my-api-key-from-api-gateway',
        }
    }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        postRequest: builder.mutation<Response, RequestBody>({
            query(body) {
                return {
                    url: '/helloworld',
                    method: 'POST',
                    body
                }
            }
        }),
    }),
})
```

When I try to use the `usePostRequestsMutation` hook in React component, I'm getting CORS errors with `403`. I checked in the browser and the preflight check query does NOT contain headers I specified in the `createApi` block. Is there a possibility to add headers for the preflight check query?
It's possible to reproduce the `403` error, by doing:

```sh
curl -v -X OPTIONS https://my-api.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/api/helloworld
```

The curl mentioned above will return `403 {"message":"Forbidden"}`. When I add required header with `X-Api-Key` to the `OPTIONS` request, then I get `HTTP 200`

```sh
curl -v -X OPTIONS -H "x-api-key: my-api-key-from-api-gateway" https://my-api.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/api/helloworld
```

To summarize - is there any way to add `x-api-key` header to the preflight check request in RTK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who is interested about the answer - I found partial solution. In AWS API Gateway it's possible to turn off API-key for the `OPTIONS` method and keep the API-key requirement for any other requests (POST in this example). I still haven't managed to send `X-API-Key` header from RTK via `OPTIONS` http method. Setting up headers with `prepareHeaders` or `headers` as it was mentioned earlier works only for `POST/GET` method.

Comment: What worked for me is, passing the "X-API-KEY" inside the "headers" object instead of prepareHeaders... can't tell why passing it in headers object worked though

Answer (score -1):

Try to `prepareHeaders` exactly as docs suggested https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery

Comment: I tried it earlier, the `preparedHeaders` are not working as well

Comment: try again! and show the code please

Comment: I changed the `baseQuery` to look like following
```typescript
baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: 'https://my-api.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/api',
        prepareHeaders: (headers) => {

            headers.set('X-Api-Key', 'my-api-key-from-api-gateway')
            headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')

            return headers
        },
    }),
```
In the browser the `x-api-key` request header does not appear in the preflight check, so the request returns `403 Forbidden`.

Comment: @kodi1911 I have the exact same error as you do. Any solution on this now, apart from disabling cors in AWS?

Comment: @JohnWinston see my answer. You have to turn off cors only for the OPTIONS request